# Array first value to repeat 3 times

Tags: php, arrays

$array =

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [type] => BUILDING_KILL
            [teamId] => 200
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [type] => BUILDING_KILL
            [teamId] => 100
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [type] => BUILDING_KILL
            [teamId] => 200
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [type] => BUILDING_KILL
            [teamId] => 100
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [type] => BUILDING_KILL
            [teamId] => 200
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [type] => BUILDING_KILL
            [teamId] => 200
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [type] => BUILDING_KILL
            [teamId] => 100
        )
    [7] => Array
        (
            [type] => BUILDING_KILL
            [teamId] => 200
        )

)
```

[teamID] => 200 repeated 3 times first.

How can i save 200 into `$firsttogive3towers` variable dynamically.

Array data will not always be same. I have no idea how to do this so i came here.

I hope i explained my question well.

Why downvote, did i ask a dumb question or break any rule?

edit : solved

Comment: But why not create a `struct` that has `type` and `teamID` and then your array will hold objects of that `struct`

Comment: Can u explain more with codes? Im new to php.

Comment: `struct`? You came from `C++`?

Comment: Start with reading [mcve]

Comment: Just to be clear, you want to get the first `teamID` that appears 3 times in your array?

Comment: @FelippeDuarte yes first teamid that repeats 3 times but i solved it

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding you correctly, you are trying to push the first three teamIDs into the array, `$firsttogive3towers`. If so, this would accomplish that:

```
for($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
   array_push($firsttogive3towers, $array[$i]['teamID']);
}
```